# Hibernate and Tibero DB

Tags: база-данных, hibernate

сущности  `DB Tibero` могут быть без `PK`. Смапленная сущность БД в код (generate persistence mappings by database schema) требует первичный ключ в `Hibernate`.

Конечно, можно считать ResultSet и дальше ее обрабатывать, но это удобно при чтении, а при записи или обновлении записи в БД придется реализовать свой велосипед.

Что вы порекомендуете? Есть ли другие ORM системы, которые могут работать без PK?

P.s. без ПК даже update невозможно делать, так как нет уникального поля, которая бы позволила точно идентифицировать запись. Все атрибуты в Tibero могут быть nullable, то есть ты можешь иметь N записей с пустыми полями.

Comment: Вообще-то практически в любой базе сущности, вернее таблицы, могут быть без PK, у всех может быть более 100500 записей null. А вот ORM без PK не работает. Надо же как-то отличать сущности друг от друга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может кому то пригодится....

создал аннотацию, чтобы определить первичный ключ

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PrimaryKey {

}

@PrimaryKey
private BigDecimal id_Row;
```

в каждом  классе прописал адрес

```
public String getPath(){ return "s.table"; }
```

получаю `ResultSet` и передаю в метод для заполнения класса

```
 /**
 * Load data from DB to collection by mapping fields from class type
 */
public Object loadObjectFromResultSet(Class classType, ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Object fieldValue;
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        Object typeOfFieldsClass = classType.newInstance();
        Field[] classFields = typeOfFieldsClass.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field : classFields) {
            fieldValue = resultSet.getObject(field.getName());
            field.set(typeOfFieldsClass, fieldValue);
        }
        objectArrayList.add(typeOfFieldsClass);
    }
    return objectArrayList;
}
```

Возвращает `List<MyEntityClass>`, где я работаю и меняю, что мне нужно

```
 //Данный метод сохраняет все
public static <T> void saveAll(List<T> objects, DataBase db) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        db.connectToTibero();
        for (T c : objects) {
            String qw = createQuery(c);
            System.out.println(qw);
            db.executeUpdate(qw);
        }
        db.executeUpdate("commit;");

    }

    private static String createQuery(Object c) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("UPDATE ");
        sb.append(getDbPath(c.getClass())).append(" set ");
        Object clazz = c;
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = c.getClass().getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
            Object value = fields[i].get(clazz);
            if(value == null)
                value = "";
            sb.append(fields[i].getName()).append(" = '").append(value).append("', ");
        }
        if (fields.length > 1) {
            sb.append(fields[fields.length - 1].getName())
                .append(" = '")
                .append(fields[fields.length - 1].get(clazz))
                .append("' ");

            Field primField = Arrays.stream(fields)
                .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(PrimaryKey.class))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("cannot found public field with annotation @PrimaryKey"));

            sb.append(" where " )
                .append(primField.getName())
                .append(" = '")
                .append(primField.get(clazz))
                .append("' ;");

            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
/**
 * Get path for table from method declared in base class type
 *
 * @return string with table path
 */
private static String getDbPath(Class classType)
    throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Object value = null;
    Object tmpObject = null;
    tmpObject = classType.newInstance();
    java.lang.reflect.Method method;
    if (tmpObject != null) {
        method = classType.getMethod("getPath");
        value = method.invoke(tmpObject);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Empty object");
    }
    return (String) value;
}
```