# Использовать ArrayList, объявленный в методе

Tags: java, arraylist

Метод возвращает данные из БД. Как использовать ArrayList usersList, объявленный в методе, для добавления новых объектов?

```
      public ArrayList<Values> getAllUsers(){
        ArrayList<Values> usersList= new ArrayList<>();
        SQL= "SELECT id,orderNo,productName,price,qty FROM Registration";
        System.out.println("Retreive values from Registration table...");
        databaseConnection();
        try {
            prepStatement= connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            resultSet= prepStatement.executeQuery();
            boolean found= false;
            while (resultSet.next()== true) {
                Values allValues= new Values();
                  allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                  allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
                  allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
                  allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
                  allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
                  usersList.add(allValues);
                  found= true;
            }
              resultSet.close();
              prepStatement.close();
              if (found) {
                return usersList;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in getAllUsers()-->"+e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            close(connection);
        }
        return (null);
    }
```

Comment: Каких новых объектов? Вы ведь и так в `usersList` добавляете объекты.

Comment: И касательно самого кода: 1. `== true` излишняя конструкция. 2. По названию метода `databaseConnection` непонятно что именно он делает с соединением к БД. 3. В данном коде `connection`, `prepStatement` и `resultSet` могут быть локальными переменными в методе - незачем делать их полями класса. 4. Открывать новое соединение с БД при каждом запросе - это весьма расточительно. 5. На мой взгляд, стоит отказаться от флага `found` и сделать ровно один `return` в конце метода: `return usersList`. Думаю, возвращение пустого списка ничуть не хуже возвращения `null` в данной ситуации.

Comment: А как добавить новую запись к таблице извлеченной из БД?

Comment: Добавить запись куда, и что вы подразумеваете под записью? Если новый объект `Values` в список `usersList`, то с помощью метода `add`, которым вы пользуетесь. Если нужно добавить новую строку в таблицу в БД, то нужно сделать соответствующий SQL-запрос `INSERT`.

Comment: Делаю админку- 1.Просматриваю всех пользователей, которые зарегистрировались. 2. Нужно редактировать этот список, те добавлять, удалять, изменять пользователей.

Comment: Как это реализовать? У меня получается только с отдельно созданным списком!?

Comment: Подскажите как с Вами связаться и объяснить подробнее, подскажите, плс!

Comment: Создайте методы `saveUser(Values user)`, `updateUser(Values user)` и `deleteUser(Values user)`, в которых делайте нужные SQL запросы. Если у вас не хватает навыков для написания своей ORM (да и необходимость этого под большим вопросом), то используйте какую-либо из существующих. Например, Hibernate. И никаких "связаться" - всё общение только через StackOverflow.

Comment: @ZhadovetsIvan лучше используйте ORM, но если что, есть уже некое решение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603350/hibernate-and-tibero-db

Comment: Спасибо! Писать Вам через комментарии или есть еще способы?